# TXMLDocument will remove entities like &#13;

Tags: xml, delphi, txmldocument

I am using TXMLDocument to process a PAD file at http://repository.appvisor.com/info/app-9f00e7003a57/DataNumen_Access_Repair_pad.xml

Below is my code(XML Vendor is MSXML):

```
procedure ProcessFile1(const SrcFileName: string);
var
  XmlFile: IXMLDocument;
begin
  XmlFile := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    XmlFile.LoadFromFile(SrcFileName);
    XmlFile.SaveToFile(SrcFileName)
  finally
  end;
end;
```

My codes just load the file and then save it. The saved version is at https://www.datanumen.com/temp/pad/DataNumen_Access_Repair_pad1.xml

I use WinMerge to compare the two versions, and find the 
 entities are all deleted in the saved version.

[image]

How to prevent this?

Comment: No idea why this is happening.  Character #13 is a return character. For some reason the code is escaping a special character when it should not (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).  My best guess is the encoding for xml is utf-8.  The character is not utf-8 and is escaping.  I think you have a unicode return character in the file that should be a utf-8 return character.

Comment: Let WinMerge **not** ignore different line breakings, then you should see it's not gone but instead just resolved to an actual byte of the value 13. Or display both in a hex viewer. Neither a "_unicode return character_" nor a "_a utf-8 return character_" [sic] exists - entities are unbound to text encodings - that's their main purpose.

Comment: @AmigoJack, After carefully checking the binary data, it is the case.

Comment: You can upvote comments if they helped you. Technically `&#13;` is the same as having `#13` directly - the XML engine parses your **entire** markup into a DOM, and when you want to save it to XML again it is re-translated from DOM to text. At that point nobody would care if the source had an entity or the appropriate byte(s). By using `TXMLDocument` you operate on the DOM, not on text. If you want it 1:1 then copy the text, not its interpretation. Changing [`.DOMVendor`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.DOMVendor) most likely won't help either.

Comment: The original XML content likely had `CRLF` line breaks in it, but whatever generator created the PAD file probably only supports `LF` and so escaped the `CR`.  Then `TXMLDocument` unescaped the `CR` and saved it as a binary byte `0x13` (since it doesn't require escaping per the XML spec) alongside the original `LF`, thus producing a valid `CRLF`, which WinMerge displays normally.